# How can I do a fresh install of OSX Mountain Lion onto my SSD for my Macbook?

Tags: macos, macbook-pro, hard-drive, ssd

My macbook is sluggish and has so much stuff that I don't use anymore and just want to start over from scratch basically. I did a time machine backup just in case something goes wrong.

- New blank SSD
- MacBook Pro (early 2011)
- backed up everything that I wanted to keep on an external HDD so that I can put it back on the SSD once OSX is installed again.

I can't directly clone everything to the SSD since my HDD has over 300GB used and my SSD is only 120GB.

Is it possible/how can I get OSX installed on my SSD without a HDD Caddy. 
There is no install disc since my Macbook came with the OS preinstalled on my HDD?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Internet Recovery

If you [installed the Internet Recovery firmware update](http://support.apple.com/kb/HT4904), hold <kbd>⌘ cmd</kbd> + <kbd>⌥ alt</kbd> + <kbd>R</kbd> on boot to begin.

[image: Internet Recovery Progress]

An image of OS X will be downloaded from the internet, and can be installed on the internal SSD normally. Once this is complete, you can restore your data from your external drive.

Comment: Ok thanks, Do I download that onto my HDD or SSD?

Comment: @Justin The OS X image: SSD. (The firmware update needs to be installed with a drive that has OS X on it already - your HDD.)

Comment: Ok so download that, discharge static, remove hdd, insert SSD, boot with that key combo?

Comment: And that link says "sorry this download is unavailable." Would updating via the appstore include the Internet recovery firmware update?

Comment: @Justin Theoretically yes - Since the firmware update was released on the Mac App Store, updating via the MAS should include that update.